# Resharper 2017 shows no mspec related naming style options

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, mspec

In Resharper 2017.3 I see no mspec related "afftected entities" under Options-> Code Editing -> C# ->Naming Style -> Advanced Settings

I tried reinstalling the Resharper Runner Plugin.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I think it's better to open an issue on the GH issue tracker for the ReSharper plugin to raise awareness with the current maintainers. Unless you already did, that is 